# Trying to return row from DB with matching column

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried ready various articles to resolve the issue to no avail. I using a form to post data to my php file.  Then I'm trying to find the row that has the matching value.  I keep getting these errors:
 Undefined index: barcode & Trying to get property of non-object
Can someone help me resolve this issue?

```
//barcode is serialized data from a form and equals 'barcode=2147483647'

$barcode = $_GET['barcode'];


$sql = "SELECT id FROM the_DB WHERE barcode = '%$barcode%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo 'id:' . $row["id"]. '<br>Name: ' . $row["item_name"]. '<br> Barcode ' . $row["barcode"]. '<br><img src="'.$row["image"].'" height="100px">';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: you only select id ?

Comment: Why do you use %? Do you mean barcode like '%...%'?

Comment: If you trying to fetching equal record then try this $sql = "SELECT id FROM the_DB WHERE barcode =".$barcode; or you can use Like query to get keyword matching result like $sql = "SELECT id FROM the_DB WHERE barcode like %".$barcode."%";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Possibility for this error:

- Check your variable in scope.
- If you get request from other page check your request method.
- If you are use session must start before use.
- echo and exit to check your variable have value or not.

You are fetching an column that are not in your result set.

```
    $barcode = $_GET['barcode'];
if(isset($barcode))
{

$sql = "SELECT * FROM the_DB WHERE barcode = '%$barcode%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;

}

}
```

Comment: May I know reason? for down vote

Comment: this states "$barcode = $_GET['barcode']; " is an unidentified index

Comment: @Raf,You can use $_Request['barcode']

Comment: check your object name is barcode or not that passed when you submit form

Comment: I used $_Request and the object is named barcode.

Comment: then what you get @raf?

Comment: I get $_Resquest is an unidentified index

Comment: echo $_Request['barcode']; exit;

Comment: Undefined variable: barcode in C:\wamp\www\mypath\index.php on line xx

Comment: It's working now! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: may I know whats problem?

Comment: @Raf,May I know whats problem?And If solved mark as complete so this is helpful.Any one else.

Comment: I change request to post

Comment: $_REQUEST is use in both cases thats why I am always prefer

Answer (score 0):

change  query as follows

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM the_DB WHERE barcode = '%$barcode%'";
```

Comment: This returns this error: Undefined index

Comment: check your table column name with parameters

Comment: and in query instead of = use like ($sql = "SELECT * FROM the_DB WHERE barcode LIKE  '%$barcode%'";)